# jQuery Rotate Arrow Image on Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have this page http://travisjterry.com/FAQ/FAQ.html

Sorry i tried to get this to work in a jsfiddle but i couldnt get it to work in there.

It is an accordion style FAQ page. And i am trying to get the arrow to rotate 90 degrees when the question is clicked. It only switches the top one, i know this is cause i am using an ID for the image, But using a class switched all of them.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
       $('#accordion div').hide();
       $('#accordion p span').click(function(){
               $("#blueArrow").rotate(90);
               $('#accordion div').slideUp();
               $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
               return false;
       });
});
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing them to classes and try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion div').hide();
    $('#accordion p span').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('p').siblings().find('.blueArrow').rotate(0);
        $(this).find('.blueArrow').rotate(90);
        $('#accordion div').slideUp();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        return false;
    });
});
```

This will target only the `.blueArrow' that's within each span, rather than all of them.

Comment: This works exactly as i asked it except i found a flaw in what i asked. After you click the next one it doesn't return the arrow the non rotated state.

Thanks for getting me 90% there though any suggestion on my next question?

Comment: Edited. Try that. Although, in my mind, most of this could be accomplished with CSS and an image sprite.

Comment: Looking at the calls you used i need to learn more jQuery i am not so good with "this" or find or closest. I also never thought about using a sprite not a bad idea but your edited code above works perfectly thank you VERY much!

Comment: Whenever you execute a function on an element, $(this) is that element inside the function. Essentially, $(this) is the element that you clicked. Find just searches through all levels of its children for the target element, and closest searches up the hierarchy until it finds what it wants. If you change to a sprite and use it as a background image or something, you can just toggle a class on the container and use that to change the image.

Comment: Very interesting. I have an understanding of those things it just never seems to work the way that i would expect it too (obviously i am doing something wrong) but i really appreciate your help today! Cheers!